# Detect from browser if specific application is installed

Tags: asp.net, javascript, ajax, web-applications

We have an advanced webpage (ASP.NET, C#), and a application which needs to be installed on the client computer in order to utilize the webpage to its fullest. The application is a tray app, and has primarily two tasks. Detect when certain events happen on the webserver (for instance invited to a meeting, or notify of an upcoming meeting). The other task the trayapp has is to use a custom protocol (trayapp://) to perform some ajax calls back to the server.

One problem we have is how to determine if the application is installed on the local machine or not. Now the user has to tick a checkbox to inform the website that the application is installed, and that it's safe to call the trayapp:// url calls.

Is there any way, for instance through a JavaScript or similar to detect if our application is installed on the local machine?

The check needs to work for IE, FF and Opera browsers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to detect with javascript inside the browser, you can probably use the collection "navigator.plugins". It works with Firefox, Opera and Chrome but unfortunately not with IE.

Update:
In FF, Opera and Chrome you can test it easily like this:

```
if (navigator.plugins["Adobe Acrobat"]) {
// do some stuff if it is installed
} else {
// do some other stuff if its not installed
}
```

Update #2:
If it is an ActiveX object in IE you can test if it exists by using something like this:

```
function getActiveXObject(name){
        try{
            return new ActiveXObject(name);
        }
        catch(err){
            return undefined;
        }
};
```

Another approach for IE is something similar to what JohnFx suggested (I found it [here](http://bytes.com/forum/thread145239.html) and have not tested it):

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\Curr entVersion\Internet
Settings\User Agent\Post Platform
```

Comment: maybe in IE he can try a CreateObject() of a registered ActiveX also from javascript to check if the application is installed

Answer (score 6):

When installing your client-side app you could modify the browser configuration to include another request header in HTTP requests and then have the server code look for that header, for example as a supported mime type using the following registry key (for Internet explorer)

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\
                                                      Internet Settings\Accepted Documents
```

I am not sure if Opera and FF use this same key, but they likely have similar configuration options, but this should at least get you on the right track.

Comment: I'm very interested in this approach but can't find any clear instruction on how.  Do you have an example of how this can be set cross-browser?

Answer (score 1):

Good idea from @JohnFx.

Another way to tackle this would be to install an ActiveX control or Browser plug-in with the trayapp installation. You could then access this in a similar way to that done when checking the version of Flash available.

Answer (score 0):

Expose the trayapp (assuming this as a Managed app) as COM object.  You could then use the  tag with the GUID and trap errors when not found or use the ActiveXobject with the progid to detect if it's installed.