# Has anyone got a simple step by step Mozilla plugin tutorial

Tags: npapi

I'm trying to create a Mozilla browser plugin for the sole purpose of detecting with javascript whether or not an application that I have written is installed. This was inspired by another [stackoverflow question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/836777/how-to-detect-browsers-protocol-handlers) on a similar subject.

All I want really is a HelloWorld type example as what I need to write will be even simpler than that. There is a lot of information on the Mozilla website, but as a plugin noob and a C++ novice I'm experiencing information overload. I just need a step by step "this is how to create your first simple plugin".

I have already written the IE equivalent by following [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/599w5e7x%28VS.80%29.aspx) ATL tutorial. This is the kind of level of guide that I would ideally like to find.

Please note, this is specifically about Mozilla plugins and not extensions - Googling this subject brings up a lot of information about extensions in addition to plugins.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Compiling_The_npruntime_Sample_Plugin_in_Visual_Studio) is a step by step guide for how to build the npruntime sample plugin using Visual Studio. When googling for info regarding Mozilla plugin development, search for npruntime. That is the scriptable plugin standard suported by Gecko (Firefox) as well as Opera and Chrome.

Comment: Awesome, that's exactly what I was looking for. Thanks for the top about googling for it in the future as well.