# How to detect in Safari if an Application is Installed

Tags: macos, safari, safari-extension

I'm attempting to write a simple plugin in safari that only needs to check if an application I have developed is installed via javascript. The application launches using a custom uri.

My issue is very similiar to the one presented [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1108693/is-it-possible-to-register-a-httpdomain-based-url-scheme-for-iphone-apps-like-y/1109200#1109200), however I'm not developing against iphone\ipad and all I really want is a true\false outcome from my check so that I can present the user with a 'download application or 'launch application' link.

I already have a windows version that works using npruntime for firefox\chrome and ATL for IE which is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2761361/has-anyone-got-a-simple-step-by-step-mozilla-plugin-tutorial)

Answer (score 0):

[Launch Services](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Carbon/Reference/LaunchServicesReference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000998-CH1g-LSCopyDefaultHandlerForURLScheme) is the API you need. See the example below:

```
#include <ApplicationServices/ApplicationServices.h>

bool check_scheme_handler(CFStringRef scheme){
    CFStringRef handler=LSCopyDefaultHandlerForURLScheme(scheme);
    if(handler){
        CFShow(handler);
        CFRelease(handler);
        return true;
    }else{
        CFShow(CFSTR("not found"));
        return false;
    }
}

int main(){
    check_scheme_handler(CFSTR("http"));
    check_scheme_handler(CFSTR("bogus"));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Sorry to be a total noob but could you elaborate a bit more about the process of me implementing and utilizing this method? A point towards a useful tutorial or walkthrough would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Well this is the way to detect if a URL scheme is supported or not. This code can be used either inside or outside of Safari plugin. The way to write a Safari/Firefox plugin would be a different question:p

Comment: It *can* be used in an NPAPI plugin, but not in a Safari Extension. Right?