# simple step by step NPAPI plugin tutorial (for developing on linux)

Tags: linux, plugins, npapi

I'm new to plugins and average in C++.

Looking for a step-by-step guide to write my first "hello world" kind of NPAPI plugin on a linux machine (Fedora 14).

Something similar to this [Has anyone got a simple step by step Mozilla plugin tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2761361/has-anyone-got-a-simple-step-by-step-mozilla-plugin-tutorial) on linux.

Comment: Maybe take a look at [FireBreath](http://www.firebreath.org/), the tutorials etc. should be easy to follow.