# How to detect an application is installed from Google Chrome?

Tags: browser, google-chrome, cross-browser

This is related to [Detect from browser if specific application is installed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/291704/detect-from-browser-if-specific-application-is-installed) but different in the way that the application I want to detect is not a plugin.

I own the software and I can do things in the setup. Under IE and Firefox I can detect it through the mimetypes, but the mime type doesn't seem registered in Chrome.