# can i check client site is installed QQ program or not?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

Morning,

I want to ask is it possible that to show a pop up message on client site, if client side pc didn't install QQ chat programs?

following is what i found through internet

```
function checkqq() {

                try {
                    new ActiveXObject("TimwpDll.TimwpCheck");
                    alert("QQ Program Installed");
                    //return true;
                } catch (e) {
                    alert("QQ Program Didn't Installed");
                    //return false;
                }
            }
```

These codes is only work in IE, it didn't work on Chrome and Firefox.
am i missing something?

Comment: This might help [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/291704/detect-from-browser-if-specific-application-is-installed)

Comment: Thank you i will check on it