# ReactJS - check the existence of local file using Javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I need to check a particular software (built by us) has been installed to the Operating system. If not need to show a proper alert message.

As an alternative solution I'm going to do something like this

After installing the software there will be file in a given path (ex: c:\mysoftware\config.txt)

If there is any way to to check the existence of this config.txt file from Javascript then I can create a function like isSoftwareInstalled() in my reactjs application.

Am i doing right thing? or is there any professional but simple way of doing this?

Comment: JS squarely does not have access to the user local files.

Comment: yes. any alternative way or method you can suggest? Thank you

Comment: Check this question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/291704/detect-from-browser-if-specific-application-is-installed

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand, you must be keeping this file somewhere on the server.
**If you are using Node/Express in the backend, you can use the Node File System readFile method.**

https://nodejs.dev/learn/reading-files-with-nodejs

If you use some other backend language, kindly use File API in that.
In case, you are wondering about client-side file read, this is not possible with JS.